# Why is my Bootstrap toggle is not working?

Tags: toggle

Hi I am new to Bootstrap, I made some changes in the standard navigation menu and the toggle menu no longer opens. Where is it wrong?

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="nav-back">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="logo">Logo</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
        aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto" id="nav-menu">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">A</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">B</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">C</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">D</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">E</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <i class="fas fa-search mr-auto" id="search"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: The information you have provided is insufficient for comment, we do not know what changed it. But I suggest you check the console to see if there is a javascript error. You can do this with Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: @Okan Except for the code I added, all sections consist of standard bootstrap template.